# How to loan my iPad while preserving personal data?

Tags: ipad, icloud, backup, restore

I would like to loan my iPad Air (iOS 8.3) to a friend and give him a clean device (without my apps and any personal data). After getting my iPad back, I would like to restore the whole configuration and have all my data again. What is the preferred procedure to do it?

Probably here's what I should do at the beginning:

1. Backup the device to a PC computer using iTunes
2. Erase the device according to the guide here: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201351 (sign out of iCloud and erase all content).

But what then? My friend should create his own iCloud account and use it to configure the device? And if I want the iPad back, then I should erase it again and restore the backup from my computer? Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you're friend is done using it, have him sign out of iCloud and then erase the iPad again. You will be asked if you want to restore from a backup while your are setting the iPad up again after the erase.